# Unique text instead of number

Tags: html, css

How can i replace numbers with mine unique text? Lets say instead of 1. , 2. , 3. i want put Bla , Blabla , Blablabla.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kf0p4.jpg

```
<style>
#menu2 {
width: 320px;
}
#menu2 ol {
font-style: talic;
font-family: Georgia, serif;
font-size: 24px;
color: #bfe1f1;
}
#menu2 ol li p {
padding:8px;
font-style: normal;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 13px;
color: #eee;
text-align:left;
border-left: 1px solid #999;
}
#menu2 ol li p em {
display: block;
}
</style>
<div id="menu2">
<ol>
  <li><p><em>Jeden</em> Sed diam eu dui dolor, porttitor laoreet fermentum. Morbi laoreet, enim aliquam convallis. Donec ullamcorper, augue euismod convallis nisl. Etiam dictum sit amet tempus arcu.</p></li>
  <li><p><em>Dwa</em> Sed diam eu dui dolor, porttitor laoreet fermentum. Morbi laoreet, enim aliquam convallis. Donec ullamcorper, augue euismod convallis nisl. Etiam dictum sit amet tempus arcu.</p></li>
  <li><p><em>Trzy</em> Sed diam eu dui dolor, porttitor laoreet fermentum. Morbi laoreet, enim aliquam convallis. Donec ullamcorper, augue euismod convallis nisl. Etiam dictum sit amet tempus arcu.</p></li>
  <li><p><em>Cztery</em> Sed diam eu dui dolor, porttitor laoreet fermentum. Morbi laoreet, enim aliquam convallis. Donec ullamcorper, augue euismod convallis nisl. Etiam dictum sit amet tempus arcu.</p></li>
</ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a little hackish..

If you want to replace the numbers with anything you want, you begin by removing the list style type.

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Next, use the `:before` pseudo, along with `:nth-child` to target the markup.

Where `content: " "` is the text preceding the list items.

```
li:before {
    content: "ugh";
    padding-right:10px;
}
li:nth-child(2):before {
    content:"blah";
}
li:nth-child(3):before {
    content:"foo";
}
```

**[jsFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/FZQEM/)**

Comment: Fair enough , thanks !